# How to synchronise/organise modules using requirejs and Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I organised the file structure of my web app, which is using [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) and [Backbone.Marionette](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html),in this way:

```
|- main.js
|- app.js
|- /subapp1
    |- subapp1.js
    |- subapp1.router.js
|- /subapp2
    |- subapp2.js
    |- subapp2.router.js
|- /colections
|- /views
```

To loads the modules I use requireJs.
Here's my code, for each module I put some questions.

---

```
// main.js
define([
    'app',
    'subapp1/subapp1.router',
    'subapp2/subapp2.router'
], function (app) {
    "use strict";
    app.start();
});
```

Questions:
1) Is right to load asynchronously the app and subapps even if subapps need app?
2) for the subApps is right to load the router which needs the app?

---

```
// app.js
/*global define*/
define([
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'models/user'
], function (Backbone, Marionette, UserModel) {
    "use strict";

    var App = new Marionette.Application();

    App.addRegions({
        header: '#header',
        sidebar: '#sidebar',
        mainColumn: '#main-column',
        rightColumn: '#right-column'
    });

    App.on("initialize:before", function () {
        this.userModel = new UserModel();
        this.userModel.fetch();
    });

    App.on("initialize:after", function () {
        Backbone.history.start();
    });

    return App;
});
```

Questions:
3) Since the `subApps` could need some `models` I decided to load it in `app.js`. Is it right this way?

---

```
// subapp1/subapp1.js
/*global define*/
define([
    'app',
    'subapp1/views/sidebarView',
    'subapp1/views/headerView'
], function (app, SidebarView, HeaderView) {
    "use strict";

    app.addInitializer(function(){
        app.header.show(new HeaderView({userModel: app.userModel}));
        app.sidebar.show(new SidebarView({userModel: app.userModel}));
    });

});
```

Questions:
4) about this module I am not sure about the `app.addInitializer`.
I am not sure for example if the `app.userModel` will be fetched when I perform `app.header.show`.
Should it be ok?

---

```
// subapp1/subapp1.router.js
/*global define*/
define([
    'marionette',
    'tasks/app'
], function (Marionette, app) {
    "use strict";
    var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

        appRoutes: {
            'tasks': 'tasks',
            'tasks/:id': 'taskDetail',
            '*defaults': 'tasks'
        }

    });

    return new Router({
        controller: app
    });
});
```

Question:
5) is it ok to load from the `main.js` the `subapp1/subapp1.router` instead of `subapp1/subapp1`?

Comment: i had similar problems.
managed to put together a staring point boilerplate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application) hope it helps ;)

Comment: you might take https://github.com/jamuhl/bmq-tmpl as a base

Answer (score 1):

### 1) Is right to load asynchronously the app and subapps even if subapps need app?

You should be able to asynchronously load your `app` and any of the `sub-apps`. If the `sub-apps` require the main `app`, they should list it as a dependency. RequireJS will resolve the dependencies for you.

Only thing you should watch out for are circular dependencies, but that shouldn't be anything you can't fix.

### 2) for the subApps is right to load the router which needs the app?

Listing the `routers` of your `sub-apps` in your `main.js` sounds right to me.

### 3) Since the `subApps` could need some `models` I decided to load it in `app.js`. Is it right this way?

A module should list any and all other modules it uses as its dependencies. Therefore, if `app.js` and `subapp1/subapp1.js` both require `models/user.js`, they should *both* list `models/user.js` as one of their dependencies.

This way, if you change any of the modules in such a way that it no longer requires `models/user.js` you can remove the dependency from that particular module without risk of missing dependencies in another module.

Besides being the savest way of managing your dependencies, it's also nice and clear for other developers or even yourself when looking at your code in the future.

### 4) about this module I am not sure about the `app.addInitializer`.

#### I am not sure for example if the `app.userModel` will be fetched when I perform `app.header.show`. Should it be ok?

Fetching data should be initiated manually. While showing a view in a `Region` does trigger the `View` to be rendered, it doesn't trigger the view's `Model` or `Collection` to fetch data.

What you can do, is to let your `view` listen to the events on your `Model` or `Collection` and re-render the view once the `Model` or `Collection` has successfully fetched new data. 
Marionette's `CollectionView` automatically binds some events to `add`, `change` and `remove` events of it's `Collection` in orde to automatically manage it's `ItemViews` if the `Collection` changes in any way.

### 5) is it ok to load from the `main.js` the `subapp1/subapp1.router` instead of `subapp1/subapp1`?

As I already stated in question 2, it's good to load your routers in `main.js`.

One reason to do this, is that you could decide not to load all your `sub-apps` up front, but instead only load them once they're actually needed. The moment such a `sub-app`'s routes get triggered is as good a time as any to load that `sub-app`'s core module and possibly some of it's dependencies, but that would of-course require the `sub-app`'s `Router` to be activated before the `sub-app` is loaded.