# Several application objects in Backbone.Marionette App

Tags: marionette

Is it possible to define several application objects in Backbone.Marionette Application? What is the best practise for creating modular application - to establish a set of application objects with distinct names, or describe specific functionality in modules extended from Marionette.Module?

Answer (score 0):

Marionette has the concept of application modules baked in.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md

```
MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.module("Foo", function(){

  // module code goes here

});

MyApp.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's all right, and documentation offers this way, but maybe for some reasons of functionality division it's useful to arrange the project in multiple apps way? I found a sort of hint here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159836/how-to-synchronise-organise-modules-using-requirejs-and-backbone-marionette?rq=1

Comment: I gotcha.  I did not realize you were looking for a require.js solution.  You may get better results if you edit your question to reflect that.  I personally prefer vanilla or CommonJS to AMD so I will be of little help :)